# swift return array from another array with contain string

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, contains

if we have an array that contain strings for example {"houssam","hassan","taleb"}

and we have a string = "ss"

I need to return an array that return the string which contain ss, so in this case we have {"houssam","hassan"}

What is the best method to do that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 7):

You can try this:

```
let string = "ss"
let array = ["houssam","hassan","taleb"]
let filtered = array.filter() { $0.containsString(string) }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let filterUsers:[String] = []
let users = [String] = ["houssam","hassan","taleb"]
let searchString = "ss"
filteredUsers = users.filter({( user: String) -> Bool in
    let stringMatch = user.rangeOfString(searchString)
    return stringMatch != nil
})
```

We filter the array of users and check to see if and where it contains "ss". It adds everything to the array where it found "ss" at least once.

Answer (score 0):

This is my demo.
var arr: Array = ["loveyou","loveher","hateyou"]
var Newarr = arr.filter({ $0.containsString("love")})
print(Newarr)

Comment: Tip: If you use the \` symbol to frame  your code snippets. It would look like `let myFoo = "Hello World"`. It would has a better readability.