# swift NSDictionary filter using string

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary

What I need is how we need to filter `NSDictionary` and return only the values and the keys where the key contain a string

For example if we have `NSDictionary` that contain :

```
{
  "houssam" : 3,
  "houss" : 2,
  "other" : 5
}
```

and the string is `"houss"`

so we need to return

```
{
  "houssam" : 3,
  "houss" : 2
}
```

Best Regards,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33648498/swift-return-array-from-another-array-with-contain-string/33648555#33648555 why create the same question twice?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `filter` function to get what you need like in the following way:

```
var dict: NSDictionary  = ["houssam": 3, "houss": 2, "other": 5 ]
let string = "houss"

var result = dict.filter { $0.0.containsString(string)}
print(result) //[("houssam", 3), ("houss", 2)]
```

The above code return a list of tuples, if you want to get a `[String: Int]` dictionary again you can use the following code:

```
var newData = [String: Int]()
for x in result {
   newData[x.0 as! String] = x.1 as? Int
}

print(newData) //["houssam": 3, "houss": 2]
```

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to get matching keys.

```
var predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF like %@", "houss");
let matchingKeys = dictionary.keys.filter { predicate.evaluateWithObject($0) };
```

Then just fetch entries which keys are in `matchingKeys` array.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an NSDictionary, you can use the `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` method on the array of keys, and fetch back the values from the initial dictionary.

For instance:

```
let data: NSDictionary = // Your NSDictionary
let keys: NSArray = data.allKeys
let filteredKeys: [String] = keys.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@", "houss")) as! [String]
let filteredDictionary = data.dictionaryWithValuesForKeys(filteredKeys)
```

Hope that helps.